# Javascript: MediaRecorder downloaded recording not playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, blob, web-mediarecorder

I am using **mediaRecorder()** API to record my audio in browser. Once the recording is **stopped**, I want that recording to be **played** on the browser and to be **downloaded** as a file on my system.

I am **able to play** the recorded audio **on the browser** as well as downloaded it on the system but the problem is that the **audio is not playing** on my system.

Below is my logic to record the audio & download it as a file on my system:

```
const mimeType = 'audio/wav';
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false });

this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType });
this.recorder.start(TIME_SLICE);

this.recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({ data }) => {
  data.size && this.audioChunks.push(data);
});

this.recorder.addEventListener('stop', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: mimeType });
  const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  this.audioChunks = [];

  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);

  anchor.style = 'display: none';
  anchor.href = audioUrl;
  anchor.download = 'file';
  anchor.click();

  document.body.removeChild(anchor);
});
```

Comment: you mean the audio file is corrupted? try to record 30 secs and tell us the size of the file

Comment: also show us the rest of the code

Comment: Rest of the code is just calling this one wrapped in a function. And I don't know if the file is corrupted.

Comment: what is recorder referring to?

Comment: It's just a class member.